# python plotly express mutiple layer graph (boxchart + scatter)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I want to create a multi layer graph with the same data frame from pandas.
One should be a boxplot and the other a scatter to see where the company is located.

Is there a way to combine both plots?

boxplot
[image]

scatterplot
[image]

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("company_index.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")
print(df)

df_u9 = df.loc[df["company"].isin(["U9"])]

fig_1 = px.box(
        df,
        x="period",
        y="index"
    )
fig_2 = px.scatter(
        df_u9,
        x="period",
        y="index"
    )

fig_1.show()
fig_2.show()
```

company_index.csv
period;index;company
1;202,4;U1
1;226,69;U10
1;235,18;U9
1;236,49;U4
1;238,13;U2
1;244,05;U6
1;252,08;U3
1;256,68;U8
1;294,99;U5
1;299,391;U7
2;243,78;U1
2;264,26;U10
2;270,6;U2
2;272,89;U9
2;285,26;U5
2;289,29;U4
2;291,15;U6
2;291,19;U3
2;305,92;U7
2;314,65;U8
3;271,82;U1
3;278,65;U2
3;296,16;U10
3;297,21;U4
3;305,93;U6
3;308,96;U5
3;323,74;U9
3;335,93;U3
3;354,13;U8
3;381,2;U7
4;281,26;U5
4;308,5;U2
4;311,61;U1
4;334,03;U4
4;335,72;U9
4;344,32;U8
4;345,27;U6
4;355,44;U3
4;373,54;U7
4;381,68;U10
5;288,6;U1
5;305,66;U5
5;323,2;U2
5;358,46;U8
5;365,57;U3
5;366,96;U10
5;368,38;U7
5;371,23;U6
5;373,63;U4
5;422,93;U9
6;285,32;U5
6;291,65;U1
6;308,68;U2
6;372,04;U8
6;376,64;U3
6;403,55;U6
6;407,38;U4
6;420,65;U10
6;423,68;U9
6;453,09;U7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution. Works rather well.
Im still struggling to understand the ".data[0]" but i believe its referring to the first fig in use. Maybe if you have multiple graphs.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("company_index.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")
print(df)

df_u9 = df.loc[df["company"].isin(["U9"])].copy()
df_u9["size"] = 1

fig = px.box(
        df,
        x="period",
        y="index"
    )
fig.add_trace(px.scatter(
        df_u9,
        x="period",
        y="index",
        size="size",
        size_max=15,
        color_discrete_sequence=(203,153,201)

    ).data[0])

fig.show()
```